# Update local storage value in javascript without jQuery support

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {
   var name = '',
     exist,
     copyObject = {},
     keys = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
   if (keys === null) {
     keys = [];
     copyObject._id = 123;
     copyObject.count = 0;
     keys.push(copyObject);
     localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(keys));
   }
   if (keys !== null) {
     for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       if (keys[i]._id === 123) {
         copyObject.count = keys[i].count += 1;
         //Here i want to update count value of Test key
         //localStorage.setItem(keys[i].count, copyObject.count);
       }
     }
   }

 }());
```

I want to Update already stored values in local storage.Above is my approach but it's not working.Here I don't want to take help of Jquery. 
[RUN](https://jsfiddle.net/mansu1101/4que3Lz8/)

Answer (score 0):

you can replace comments with these lines.

```
//Here i want to update count value of Test key
```

localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(keys));

Comment: I can not upvote my reputation is below 15 please you first upvote my quetion. so will do same.

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts works.
 just delete `=+ 1` and do it like this :

`copyObject.count = keys[i].count + 1`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well
localStorage.setItem(keys[i].count, copyObject.count);